# Laravel 8 ERROR :Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\PostController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am new in laravel 8, I add new Controller and edit web.php but still have this error:'Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\PostController] does not exist'

this is PostController.php

```html
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers;


class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('articles');
    }

}
```

web.php

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index' );
```

i also tried the other solution by adding namespace but  doesnt work

```html
$namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

it give me this error: "Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found"

if anyone here can explain to me where is the problem I will be thankful

Comment: Try `Route::get('/',[PostController::class, 'index'] );` as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-default-route-files)

Answer (score 0):

just convert this to this code

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index' );
```

By this one :

```
enter code here

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('/',[PostController::class, 'index']);
```

the error is you have written a laravel 7 , 6,etc code so the new routes in laravel 8 is like this [NameOfController::class,'name_of_method'] ,
you can take a look at laravel 8 docs
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: thankyou for you answer. But I really have already testing this code but doesn't work its give this error:  Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Answer (score 0):

This is happing because default namespace is removed from laravel 8. You should enable from your RouteServiceProvider like below by uncommenting line

```
 /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/backend/dashboard';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; //uncomment this
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. But  as I have already mentioned i added the namespace to the RouteServiceProvider and it doesn't work it give this error: Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Comment: I analyzed your  web.php file and you have imported namespace for controller. As you have uncommented namespace in routeseviceprovider . so there is no need to import controllers in web.php again.

Comment: if everything goes well then your controllers path will be 
[App\Http\Controllers\PostController] does not exist

Comment: when i added the namespace to RouteServiceProvider i didn't import controllers in web.php i just mentioned that i tried the 2 solutions: solution1 where i  imported the  Controllers in web.php. and solution2 where i added the nameSpace to the RouteServiceProvider without importing the controller in web.php . But the problem is that nothing work. there is something  but i dont know what is it